# Hough Lines P - How to know if there is no line detected?

Tags: opencv, lines, identify

I used `HoughLinesP` to identify lines. However, my problem is how do I know when there are no lines detected. I have tried comparing the vector lines to null but nothing happens. To be precise, here is my code:

```
for(size_t k=0; k<lines.size(); k++){
    Vec4i l = lines[k];
    line(gray, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    double x = l[2]-l[0];
    double y = l[3]-l[1];
    double slope = (x/y);
    double rad = atan(slope);
    double pi = 3.1416;
    double deg = (rad*180)/pi;
    double fin = deg+90;

    int part = 0;
    if (lines.empty()){printf("NO LINE IN THIS PORTION OF THE IMAGE!");part = 0;}
    else{
        if (fin>=0 && fin<=45){part = 1;}
        else if (fin>45 && fin<=90){part = 2;}
        else if (fin>90 && fin<=135){part = 3;}
        else if (fin>135 && fin<=180){part = 4;}
    }
    printf("portion number = %d angle = %f PART = %d\n",j, fin, part);
}
```

I am identifying a particular sector with the `part` variable. If there are no lines detected, I would like for `part == 0` to be true. But, I can't find the correct way to know if there are no lines detected. It is only printing angles if there is already a line in the image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check if the `lines` vector is empty outside of the loop. The way you have it setup now `lines` will never be detected as empty because the loop only executes if `lines.size() > 0`.

Here is a fix:

```
int part = 0;
double fin = -1.0; // just an arbitrary sentinel value (can be whatever you want here).

if(lines.empty())
{
    part = 0;
    fin  = -1.0;
    printf("portion number = %d angle = %f PART = %d\n",j, fin, part);
    printf("NO LINE IN THIS PORTION OF THE IMAGE!");
}
else
{
    for(size_t k=0; k<lines.size(); k++){
        Vec4i l = lines[k];
        line(gray, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
        double x = l[2]-l[0];
        double y = l[3]-l[1];
        double slope = (x/y);
        double rad = atan(slope);
        double pi = 3.1416;
        double deg = (rad*180)/pi;
        fin = deg+90;

        if (fin>=0 && fin<=45){part = 1;}
        else if (fin>45 && fin<=90){part = 2;}
        else if (fin>90 && fin<=135){part = 3;}
        else if (fin>135 && fin<=180){part = 4;}

        printf("portion number = %d angle = %f PART = %d\n",j, fin, part);
    }
}
```